# Collect and batch process HTTP GET Requests in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have an ASP.NET application which *transforms* `HTTP GET` requests into web service calls.

Now each request results in a web method call. I would like to **collect** or **group** the data from the requests to execute less service calls. So each request should check if a *processor object* exists and accept more data.

Then pass the data to this object or create a new *processor object*. The maximum waiting period of time for a request to be passed to the service would normally be in the range of seconds or maybe a couple of minutes.

Is there a nice pattern for this?